# Node Request Module - is there a way to make sure the connection is terminated after an API call

Tags: node.js, node-request

In Request Module I have not seen any on disconnect or end.
How to make sure the http request is closed. is the library handling this for us? If so Cannot find so in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

request module take care of that for all types of requests.see below function they have in their module and being called in each type request accordingly..

```
Request.prototype.end = function (chunk) {
var self = this
if (chunk) {
self.write(chunk)
}
if (!self._started) {
self.start()
}
self.req.end()
}
Request.prototype.pause = function () {
var self = this
if (!self.responseContent) {
self._paused = true
} else {
self.responseContent.pause.apply(self.responseContent, arguments)
}
}
Request.prototype.resume = function () {
var self = this
if (!self.responseContent) {
self._paused = false
} else {
self.responseContent.resume.apply(self.responseContent, arguments)
}
}
Request.prototype.destroy = function () {
var self = this
if (!self._ended) {
self.end()
} else if (self.response) {
self.response.destroy()
}
}
```

Comment: Does that mean we need to call request.end explicitly or is it taken care implicitly?(On natural end of the request or after timeout)